# Using Spring by Creating Multiple ApplicationContexts to manage bean life time - is this okay?

Tags: spring

I have used Spring before but I am no expert and only used it for standard web-development previously.

Currently, I am working on a project where Spring is being used very differently.  It's a stand-alone Swing app which has many displays and the user can switch between a display via a toolbar.  When the display changes, all the components need to be destroyed (garbage-collected).

Currently, this is done by having separate ApplicationContexts associated with each display.  So when the display is changed, the idea is that the AppCtx associated with the display is destroyed then a new app context is created (from a different XML file) to load the components in the new display.

Is this an appropriate way of using Spring?  I don't know much about the internals of the Spring Container and the way the container manages the beans so I can't figure out whether it's a good thing or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you should be using a [custom scope](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-custom).

> As of Spring 2.0, the bean scoping mechanism in Spring is extensible. This means that you are not limited to just the bean scopes that Spring provides out of the box; you can define your own scopes, or even redefine the existing scopes (although that last one would probably be considered bad practice - please note that you cannot override the built-in singleton and prototype  scopes).

The problem with your approach is mainly performance, as you will be parsing/configuring/defining/instantiating spring beans on every screen change. I suggest you use instead a custom scope of `screen` ( let's say ), which returns separate objects per scope.

See the [Scope javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/Scope.html) for implementation details.

Comment: Thanks, I have just read about Scopes and they sound like exactly what I need!